# TCP connection between 2 raspberryPI

Tags: c, tcp, raspberry-pi

I wrote C code to control traffic lights between 2 raspberry Pi, and it works perfectly. However, I have a huge problem: I wrote all the code on my desktop computer and I wanted to change to my laptop. So I changed the IP address in my client, and now the TCP connection fails...

So I run my server.c first, and then my client.c, but after few seconds, I have the message "Connection failed". I really don't understand why, because it worked in my other computer with the same configuration. I give you only the code with the TCP connection.

Here is my code for the connection:

client.c:

```
/* TCP Variables*/
int sock = 0, valread;
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
char *hello = "Hello from client";
char buffer[1024] = {0}; // message receive from RaspberryPI 1

void configurationTCP()
{
    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        printf("\n Socket creation error \n");
        
    }
   
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
       
    // Convert IPv4 and IPv6 addresses from text to binary form
    if(inet_pton(AF_INET, "192.168.137.193", &serv_addr.sin_addr)<=0) 
    {
        printf("\nInvalid address/ Address not supported \n");
        
    }
   
    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
    {
        printf("\nConnection Failed \n");
       
    }
    
}

int main()
{
    // Start Message
    printf("test!!\n");
    
    // Enter Start Button
    scanf("hey");
    configureGPIOs();
    launchTests();


    // COnfigure TCP connection : 

  configurationTCP();
}
```

server.c:

```
void configurationTCP()
{
    // Creating socket file descriptor
    if ((server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == 0)
    {
        perror("socket failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
       
    // Forcefully attaching socket to the port 8080
    if (setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT,
                                                  &opt, sizeof(opt)))
    {
        perror("setsockopt");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    address.sin_port = htons( PORT );
       
    // Forcefully attaching socket to the port 8080
    if (bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, 
                                 sizeof(address))<0)
    {
        perror("bind failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (listen(server_fd, 3) < 0)
    {
        perror("listen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if ((new_socket = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, 
                       (socklen_t*)&addrlen))<0)
    {
        perror("accept");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this computer has some firewall

Comment: Maybe running `fuser -k port_number_here/tcp` help

Comment: I think I deactivated all the firewall

Comment: And the command doesn't change anything..... Still "Connection failed". It's a new computer, maybe I have to do something ?

Comment: <O/T> where are you getting _two_ Pis??? I can't even find one...

Comment: What do u mean?

Comment: @Jeanlqs I think yano means that they're currently sold out in many places.

Comment: Consider downloading some sniffer (Wireshark, tcpdump on Linux/Mac) and start sniffing on the responder side to see if anything coming through... 
You should see the 3-Way [handshake](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tcp-3-way-handshake-process/). If for example you're seeing FIN flag then it means responder side rejected the connection